# Listing inputs from a form into an array - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Hey I am trying to get input from a bunch of input boxes into an array in javascript

```
function lagreBilett(){
    let inputElement = document.getElementsByName("bilett");
    let bilett = {};
    inputElement.forEach ((info) => {
        bilett[info.id] = info.value;

        info.value = '';
    });

    console.log(bilett);

    let ut = "";
    const biletter = [];
    biletter.push(bilett);
    for(let bilett of biletter){
        ut += "Antall: " + bilett["antall"] + " Fornavn: " + bilett["fornavn"] + " Etternavn: " + bilett["etternavn"]
        + " Telefonnr: " + bilett["telefonnr"] + " Epost: " + bilett["epost"];
    }

    document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = ut;
}
```

But everytime i call upon the function, instead of creating a new object and putting it into the array with the other object, it just replaces it and creates a new one, this i think is because it has the same name, is their anyway to solve this?

Comment: _"it just replaces it and creates a new one"_ - No, it doesn't replace anything. `biletter` is only available in `lagreBilett`. As soon as you leave that function the variable `biletter` no longer exists.

Comment: *" putting it into the array with the other object"*: Your function does not *add* to an existing array, but creates a new, empty one with `biletter = [];`. But maybe you just want to append to the output using `innerHTML +=` instead of `innerHTML =`. Is that what you wanted?